# Ubuntu server, postgresql, python, "Peer auth failed"

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu

Hi I'm getting the following and the other solutions I've seen for this don't seem to be working... 
Within the ubuntu server terminal (a virtualbox vm):
Error FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "a4apps"

My Ubuntu server os user name is the same.
I have restarted my postgres.
I have tried changing my pg_hba.conf file by:
changing the IPv4 host method from md5 to "trust"
and by adding a line under it "host   all    all    myubuntuserverip/32   trust"

I am trying to access it via a python script.
I am using psycopg

```
con = psycopg2.connect(database='fieldtest2', user='a4apps')
```

I created the user: sudo -u postgres create user a4apps
superuser no, create databases yes, create other users no.
Created database: sudo -u postgres createdb fieldtest2 -O a4apps

I was following this tutorial: [here](http://zetcode.com/db/postgresqlpythontutorial/)

I'm running out of ideas. Any guidance would be appreciated.
Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This specific error message:

> Peer authentication failed for user "a4apps"

means that the `peer` authentication method was selected per `pg_hba.conf` **and** that the connection attempt was not made by the OS user `a4apps`, contrary to what this auth method requires.

The default Ubuntu `pg_hba.conf` has these lines:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
```

To allow local passwordless connections for any user except `postgres`, you may replace `peer` by `trust` in the last line.

The IPv4-related changes you tried in `pg_hba.conf` had no effect on your script because it doesn't connect through TCP/IP. If the connection string mentioned a hostname, it would then use TCP/IP and trigger the corresponding rules in `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: That was hugely helpful. Thank you. It works, and I now understand why. Just had to remember to restart postgres after the changes.